# Getting WGET to display a less verbose output

Tags: windows, linux, wget

Is it possible to get WGET to only show download progress e.g. download bar, opposed to all of the connection info, as it does look a little ugly on the client side, is this possible to do?

Answer (score 103):

You can use:

```
wget --no-verbose ...
wget -nv ...
```

to make wget less verbose. When I saw "less verbose" I mean that you get:

- one printed line of text with the file name for each download
- no progress bar

Comment: This doesn't show the progress bar...

Answer (score 63):

There's an [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29457649/241211) that does this:

```
wget -q --show-progress http://example.com
```

`--show-progress` will override the "quiet" flag.

<sub>For wget <1.16, use [this excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/1551463/23156) instead.</sub>

Comment: should be the accepted answer as it relates to wget specifically.

Comment: This answer still makes it spam the stdout with a gigantic progress bar. In the comments of the answer you linked however there's a solution, together with -q and --show-progress, you should add: --progress=bar:force:noscroll

Comment: In wget 1.14: `unrecognized option '--show-progress'`

Answer (score 20):

The following option works great to show minimum progress without complete silence like `-q`:

```
wget --progress=bar:force:noscroll https://repo.anaconda.com/...
```

For wget 1.16+, use `-q --show-progress` to show the progress bar only, as mentioned in [an earlier answer](https://superuser.com/a/1037729/23156).

```
wget -q --show-progress https://repo.anaconda.com/...
```

Comment: This is the best answer, if you're reading this after 2020.

Answer (score 6):

Try [**`curl`**](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32) instead...

```
$ curl "http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.21.6.tar.lzma" -o nul
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 11 1838k   11  213k    0     0   7996      0  0:03:55  0:00:27  0:03:28 18096
```

...or **`curl -#`**:

```
$ curl "http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.21.6.tar.lzma" -o nul -#
#########                                                                 13,3%
```